# 'IN' operator is not working correctly while getting SQL rule in Query Builder Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, query-builder

I am trying to use multiple selection in jquery query builder then create the Sql rule as you see below 
[image]

I have an issue with multiple selection while creating the sql rule. for example here instead of getting `country IN('Australia','Germany')` I am getting `country IN('Australia,Germany')` which is causing issue when I extrat my data based on this rule.

It's like taking all the selected items as one string. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>x86 Query Builder</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.maatwebsite.nl/demo-builder/bower_components/selectize/dist/css/selectize.css"> -->

  <link href="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css"> 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 
  <!-- <script src="http://www.maatwebsite.nl/demo-builder/bower_components/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
 <script src="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container"> 
   <div id="builder"></div> 
   <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn-get-sql">SQL</button>

   <script>
  data = '[{"id": 1,"name": "Germany"},{"id": 2,"name": "Austria"},{"id": 3,"name": "USA"},{"id": 4,"name": "Australia"}]'; 

$('#builder').on('afterCreateRuleInput.queryBuilder', function(e, rule) {
  if (rule.filter.plugin == 'selectize') {
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container').css('min-width', '200px')
      .find('.selectize-control').removeClass('form-control');} });

$('#builder').queryBuilder({
  plugins: [
    'bt-tooltip-errors',
    'not-group'
  ],
  filters: [{ id: 'country',
    label: 'country',
    type: 'string',
    plugin: 'selectize',
    operators: ['equal','in'],
    plugin_config: {
      valueField: 'name',
      labelField: 'name',
      searchField: 'name',
      sortField: 'name',
      create: false,
      // maxItems: 1,
      plugins: ['remove_button'],
      onInitialize: function() {
        var that = this;
          JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(item) {
              that.addOption(item);
              console.log(item); }); } },
      valueSetter: function(rule, value) {
       rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.setValue(value);} }] }); 

    $('#btn-get-sql').on('click', function() {
  var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getSQL', false);
  // console.log(result);
  if (result.sql.length) {
    alert(result.sql);}
});
</script> 

   </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

I was searching in many forums, I found this `value_separator: ','` to add it my filter but it wasn't working. I tried also to create a value setter and customize it but I wasn't successful to make it work.

Any suggestion please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is kinda dirty workaround but try having a checking on the code behind to see if an IN/NOT IN operator is used. If it is, then parse the corresponding value and re-format it so country names are enclosed with quotes.

Comment: Hi @JuniorDev, have you find a solution to this I'm also having the same issue.Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's been three months since this question was asked. But in case anyone is struggling with the same issue, the solution below solved my problem:

```
input: 'select', // this is important
multiple: true, // this is too
```

Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/685)